# Javascript or jQuery auto populate one input text based on another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am not good at JS or jQuery. I take the follow code for better explaining what I what. When a user input 400 or more to triglycerides, the LDL is autopopulated with 'N/A'. How do I implement JS or jQuery to do that? Thanks

```
<form>
 <input name='triglycerides" value="" />
 <input name='LDL' value="" />
</form>
```

My actual code is as follows:

```
$('#ldl_override').keyup(function(){
var val = parseInt($(this).val());
if(val > 399)
   $('#qIn726').val('N/A');
});


 elseif($ldl_override && $questionID == 728)
 {
  $question .= "<input $maxLengthString id=\"ldl_override\" name=\"field[" . $questionID . "]\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($answer) . "\" />\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

with jquery:

```
<form>
 <input name="triglycerides" value="" onChange="javascript: if($('#triglycerides').val() > 400) $('#LDL').val('N/A'); />
 <input id="LDL" name='LDL' value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: The use of an `onchange` attribute with jQuery code kind of makes me want to weep...

Comment: Hi, Sascha, I tried your method, but didn't get it work. Please see my updated question and see if you have any idea on this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with jQuery

```
$('input[name="triglycerides"]').keyup(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(val > 399)
       $('input[name="LDL"]').val('N/A');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you need to add anything to the html form?

Comment: no, just make sure to use IDs for elements, its easier to get element by id than searching it by attributes example <input type="text" id="LDS" /> then your js would look like $('#LDS').val('N/A');

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. I don't know why. I modified my question and added some real code, please help me to take a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` to select with `#`! For example:

HTML:

```
<form>
 <input id="triglycerides" value="" />
 <input id="triglycerides-result" value="" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#triglycerides').keyup(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (val > 399)
       $('#triglycerides-result').val('high');
    else
       $('#triglycerides-result').val('normal');
});
```

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGzLV/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="triglycerides"]').change(function() {
   var val = parseInt($(this).val());
   if(val > 399) {
      $('#LDL').val('N/A')  
   }
});
```